# Como optimizar la búsqueda de un dato dentro de un DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

Tengo un DataTable que lo lleno en una primera instancia con una consulta sql. Posteriormente con ciclo `foreach` recorro una lista, en la que llamo el `DataTable`. Para acotar la búsqueda le aplico el `if`.

La idea de esto, es como puedo filtrar directamente por un atributo determinado. Ejemplo de Código:

```
 public void readInfo(int empresa, int periodo, int mes, int obra, List<FichasPersonModel> list1, dynamic conecta)
    {

        DataTable dt_liquidaciones = new DataTable();

        string sql = " SELECT tipo,id,valor, number from liquidations";
        sql += " WHERE empresa=@empresa AND";
        sql += " periodo=@periodo AND";
        sql += " mes=@mes AND obra=@obra ORDER BY number";
        MySqlDataAdapter datos_l = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conecta);
        datos_l.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empresa", empresa);
        datos_l.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periodo", periodo);
        datos_l.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", mes);
        datos_l.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obra", obra);
        datos_l.Fill(dt_liquidaciones);
        int number = 0;

        foreach (var ficha in list1)
        {


            foreach (DataRow dato_liquidacion in dt_liquidaciones.Rows)
            {
                number = Convert.ToInt32(dato_liquidacion[3]);
                if (number == ficha.number)
                {
                    //code
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Mi pregunta es si puedo recorrer el `DataTable` solo con el filtro del valor `number`, para evitar recorrer otros datos que no son necesarios. Si existe alguna sentencia
de `Where`, algo como:

```
DataTable dt_liquidaciones2  =  dt_liquidaciones.Where(x=>x.number== ficha.number).ToList();

foreach (DataRow dato_liquidacion2 in dt_ dt_liquidaciones2.Rows)
                {
///COde Insert
}
```

La idea es poder optimizar la búsqueda, y no hacer recorridos innecesarios en el foreach. Desde ya, gracias por si aporte

Answer (score 2):

La clase `DataTable` tiene un método `Select` que devuelve un arreglo de `DataRow`.
Así que una opción sería utilizar:

```
string filtro = $"number = {ficha.number}";
DataRow[] resultado = dt_liquidaciones.Select(filtro);
```

Considero importante destacar el hecho de que cualquier operación de filtrado sobre una colección, siempre hace un recorrido de toda la colección, no importa si utilizas los iteradores (`for`, `foreach`, etc.) directamente en el programa como lo haces ahora, Linq o cualquier método ofrecido por la colección.

Las diferencias son básicamente escribir más o menos líneas de código y en consecuencia un código más simple o complejo de leer.

Comment: Entonces solo mejoraría el código a mas corto, pero no mejoraría el rendimiento, se demoraría lo mismo en procesar.

Comment: No hay una formula única para obtener un mejor rendimiento, pienso que no solo se trata de velocidad sino de los recursos que consume la solución. Mi recomendación, si tienes algo de tiempo es que hagas una prueba con diferentes opciones a ver cual tiene mejor desempeño en tu escenario particular. En lo personal, casi todas las pruebas que he hecho para diferentes escenarios, siempre gana un simple ciclo `for`

Comment: larespuesta es correcta.. pero no seria muchisimo mejor hacerlo directamente en sql??? digo, asi no viajan montones de datos que no se usan...

Comment: Eso en realidad depende del tamaño de tu conjunto de datos. Una regla general es que mientras menos consultas hagas al manejador de base de datos es mejor. Si la cantidad de fichas no es muy larga, puedes agregar en el where de sql una condicion mas 'and numero IN (1,5,7) por ejemplo. Tambien puedes utilizar un SqlDataReader en lugar de un DataTable.

Comment: el SqlDataReader, sería mas eficiente que meterlo en un DataTable?

Comment: Afirmativo, solo debes tener en cuenta que el SqlDataReader crea flujo de datos (stream) que solo puedes recorrer de principio a fin (forward-only). Si bien usar el SqlDataReader te hará cambiar un poco la lógica, tendrás un mejor rendimiento y un menor impacto en la memoria porque podrás descartar lo que no te interese. Vale destacar que en conjuntos de datos muy pequeños la diferencia puede ser imperceptible. En la documentación de [SqlDataReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) hay un ejemplo que te puede orientar.

Comment: Por el DataAdapter en tu código creo que estás utilizando MySql, si este caso en lugar de SqlDataReader debería ser [MySqlDataReader](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm).

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez, otra consulta, como yo utilizo MySqlDataAdapter y meto los datos en un datatable, sería mas conveniente que use MySqlDataReader y y ahí recorra los datos para meterlo en un datatable?

Comment: No serviría de mucho porque el DataAdapter internamente usa un DataReader para llenar el DataTable. Para aprovechar los beneficios de un DataReader será necesario cambiar el enfoque que tienes actualmente. Pero sin más detalles acerca de cómo está estructurada la información y lo que haces con ella no será posible hacer recomendaciones.

Comment: Si tenes una coleccion ordenada si hay formas de mejorar la velocidad de una manera abismal. Cualquier consulta hace una busqueda lineal entonces realiza el bucle hasta encontrar el resultado. La consulta seria mejor en la base de datos, por clave y el motor hace la busqueda en forma de arbol, entonces no recorre todos los datos. Tambien se puede hacer la consulta en paralelo y esto tambien mejora la velocidad.

Comment: Hola @Danilo, estuve repasando tu requerimiento y se me ocurren algunas formas que pueden mejorar el rendimiento usando el DataTable y otras utilizando otros tipos de datos en combinación con MySqlDataReader pero antes de agregarlas a mi respuesta me gustaría saber si aún tienes el requerimiento y de ser así por favor aclárame 2 dudas **1** ¿la lista que recibes en `list1` puede tener valores repetidos en el `numero` de ficha? **2** En el resultado de la consulta a SQL ¿puede tener dos o más registros con el mismo número?.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias ayudarte con linq

[Consultas en LINQ to DataSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset)

entonces usarias

```
var numbers = list1.Select(x=> x.number).ToList();

var query = dt_liquidaciones.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(p => numbers.Contains(p.Field<int>("number")))
                   .ToList();
```

Si de la query quieres obtener nuevamente un datatable vas a tener que convertirlo

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Comment: Gracias Leandro por la respuesta, esto optimizaría la busqueda para no estar haciendo el if dentro del foreach? Asi me dedicaría exclusivamente a recorrer la lista query que has definido. Edite la pregunta, ya que estaba mal escrita la declaración de la función al principio

Comment: Claro ya no necesitarias el foreach ni el if, pero porque necesitas recorrer la query ?

Comment: Lo que pasa Leandro, es que cuando obtenga el filtro por el number, todos los que estan en esa lista, debo hacer unas llamadas a otras funciones para operar

Comment: No se que sera eso de operar, pero en la pregunta planteas solo filtrar los datos de un datatable, no mencionaste nada de que vas a hacer luego con esa informacion. Las respuestas que podemos dar en en base a lo que nos cuentas, despues no podemos adivinar

Comment: Leandro, me refiero que los que estan en el listado de numbers, hacer calculos de llamar a funciones que suman y concadenen string, cosas así

Comment: Pero concatenar y sumar podrias hacerlo en el mismo linq, usando el Select(), digo si son operaciones con los datos del mismo datatable